# How do I get Platform Role with c# desktop app?

Tags: c#, system, platform, role

I've been trying to get the **Platform Role** value shown in the System information window.

How can I get this?

[image: System Information window]

Thanks!

Comment: Show your "try"...

Comment: From what I can tell, the values for that item seem to map to the [Power_Platform_Role enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373174(v=vs.85).aspx)